# kivy install fails on github-actions while runs-on:windows-latest

Tags: python, windows, pip, kivy, github-actions

I am trying to automate building binaries for windows from the python program that depends on [kivy](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/). The manual build for Linux and windows is available at [**FormHelper**](https://formhelper.mgeek.in/).

While building for windows with GitHub actions the action fails to install kivy.

kivy install fails on Github-actions while runs-on:windows-latest

### Github actions workflow

```yaml
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a single version of Python
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-python

name: compile-source-windows

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
    paths:
      - "**/src/*.py"
      - "**/src/*.bat"
      - "**/src/*.sh"
      - "**/compile-source-windows.yml"
  workflow_dispatch:

# on: workflow_dispatch
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: "./source/01FormHelper/src/"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: update pip and install python modules in pipenv
        run: |
          python -V
          pip install -U pip
          pip install pipenv
          pip install Kivy
          pip install kivy pyinstaller beautifulsoup4 setuptools cython 
          pipenv install cython 
          pipenv install kivy 
          pipenv install Kivy
```

it works on ubuntu-latest

### error log

```bash
Installing kivy...
Error:  An error occurred while installing kivy!
Error text: Collecting kivy
  Downloading Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
     --------------------------------------- 23.8/23.8 MB 28.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  � pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  \u2502 exit code: 1
  \u2570\u2500> [13 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Downloading setuptools-66.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 1.3/1.3 MB 26.6 MB/s eta 
0:00:00
      Collecting wheel
        Downloading wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Downloading Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
           ------------------------------------- 983.8/983.8 kB 20.7 MB/s eta 
0:00:00
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Downloading kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl 
(3.9 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 3.9/3.9 MB 35.2 MB/s eta 
0:00:00
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem 
with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

� pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
\u2502 exit code: 1
\u2570\u2500> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with
pip.

Installation Failed
Installing Kivy...
Error:  An error occurred while installing Kivy!
Error text: Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  � pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  \u2502 exit code: 1
  \u2570\u2500> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-66.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl 
(3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem 
with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

� pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
\u2502 exit code: 1
\u2570\u2500> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with
pip.

Installation Failed
```

Comment: I see this text 'gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64' which makes me suspicious there is an unsupported Python3.11 version being referenced.  I am not familiar with github actions but I am with Kivy and Python.  What version runs if you simply execute python from the terminal?  are you working with virtual environments?

Comment: Yes, I am using `pipenv` for virtual env. However, I also tried to install kivy outside pipenv with `pip install kivy`. I am using python 3.10.